# Python: How to piggyback on existing tests when developing third party packages

Tags: python, django

My [PR](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/pull/4540) on django-rest-framework to add in a "hybrid pagination" got rejected reason being better to be in a 3rd party package.

So I went ahead and created the package structure but got stuck in creating the test, if you have a look at the [PR files changed](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/pull/4540/files), my new tests are merely extending the existing tests and changed to use my new pagination class.

```
 +class TestCombinedPaginationPageNumber(TestPageNumberPagination):
 +    def setup(self):
 +        class ExamplePagination(pagination.HybridPagination):
 +            page_size = 5
 +
 +        self.pagination = ExamplePagination()
 +        self.queryset = range(1, 101)
 +
 +
 +class TestCombinedPaginationLimitOffset(TestLimitOffset):
 +    def setup(self):
 +        class ExamplePagination(pagination.HybridPagination):
 +            default_limit = 10
 +            max_limit = 15
 +
 +        self.pagination = ExamplePagination()
 +        self.queryset = range(1, 101)
```

I am having trouble working out a way to piggyback these tests in my own 3rd party tests, I can't extend it remotely since installing the package doesn't include test files. I tried copying the particular `test_pagination.py` file but getting a lot of errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct that you won't be able to include the tests from the `pip install` package. You'll need to clone whichever bits of test case you want to replicate locally.

> I tried copying the particular test_pagination.py file but getting a lot of errors.

I'd suggest starting off small. Take a single test case that you want to replicate. Copy *just that one*, and also any imports it relies on.

More generally you should probably just try to exclusively test the bits that your package adds, rather than re-testing REST framework's behavior. Eg for your "switch between pagination styles", don't aim to test the pagination itself, but rather the switching behavior.

Hope that helps. If you've any issues with resolving specific errors while writing the test case please do shout out on the REST framework mailing list.